# How do I use Error Handling Application Block for WPF Unhandled Exceptions?

Tags: wpf, exception, enterprise-library, unhandled-exception

After I catch an unhandled exception via Application.DispatcherUnhandledException or AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException, how should I use the Enterprise Library Error Handling Application Block to do the handling? Can anyone demonstrate some sample code, etc?

How can the end-user easily send the exception details back to developers?

Basically, I'm looking for some guidance on what best practice is after the unhandled error is caught.

Answer (score 0):

"Enterprise Library" allows you to create exception handling policies as per the CLR `Type` of the error. You can use the  `DispatcherUnhandledException` and `UnhandledException` types for the same.

Comment: Yes I'm aware of this - I'm catching unhandled errors ok, but what should I do with them once I've got them? My question is how do I log and\or send the unhandled exception details back to the developer **after** its been caught? I was hoping someone could demonstrate some sample code or best practice guidance.

Comment: That is what I said. Create policies of "how" you want the exception of types `DispatcherUnhandledException` and `UnhandledException` to **reveal** itself to the developer / support / user. Enterprise Library Policiies allow you to do exactly that. There are a lot of examples on web of which type of exceptions to present to the target actor (developer / user / support) and **HOW**.

Comment: Thanks AngelWPF but I'm struggling to find the examples you refer to. Can you provide any links?

Comment: http://weblogs.asp.net/sukumarraju/archive/2009/10/04/microsoft-enterprise-library-4-1-exception-handling-block.aspx... in this example he has selected generic `Exception` type from the list, you need to use `DispatcherUnhandledException` and `UnhandledException` types.